# Why does my model wrinkle when I pose the Rig?

Tags: rigging

I am not sure what else to add to this question  other than I dont know why the arm on my model is bending in multiple spots after posing. I  assume it should just be bending ad where I bend the rig?

Thank you so much for any help.[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe recalculate the normals before parenting? Or please share your file

Comment: That to me looks like what can happen when multiple bones are fighting for influence over the same vertices. If the total of deform weights on any given vertices goes over 1, you will have issues. It would help if you could post a sample file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to add the provided download link.